# Craft reCAPTCHA Plugin (Matt West)

Tags: craft3, plugins, plugin-recaptcha

Has anyone tried using the Craft reCAPTCHA plugin from Matt West? The issue I am experiencing is that if a Contact Form is submitted without ticking the reCAPTCHA widget, the form does not submit - that's good! - but there is no error message posted on the form page to remind the user to 'prove they are human'

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: From a User Experience point of view I use the Pixel & Tonic honeypot plugin. It takes responsibility of spam filtering away from the user. But I’m response to your actual question, sorry, bud, I’m no help there.

Comment: @Jay On the flip side, the honeypot technique is minimally effective.  I feel like most bots/scripts are smart enough to get around it.

Comment: @BradBell this is a good point. At this stage, I'm only dealing with clients that are getting hundreds of emails, not thousands. So a honeypot seems to have worked enough for their needs.

Comment: My experience with the Honeypot field approach aligns with @BradBell comment